# SSRS default URL not being referenced from Windows application

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssl, ssrs-2016

I have installed and configured SSRS and when I check the URL via HTTP it works fine (I haven't configured SSL).

When I try to run a report from the Windows application, I get the following error message:

> Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it xxx.xx.xxx.xx:443

But I am not trying to get to port 443, I am trying to get to the default port 80. I'm not sure why the windows application is trying to access port 443.

Additional Info:

The Windows application and SSRS is on the same server using the same network.
The server is part of a load balancer which has a SSL certificate.

Comment: it looks like your windows app is trying to connect to HTTPS for SSRS. Port 443 is the default port of SSL url for SSRS

Comment: Yeah.It is trying to connect to HTTPS,but i want my Windows app to connect to HTTP only.

Comment: Have you configured the [firewall](https://arcanecode.com/2018/01/02/opening-port-80-in-windows-firewall-to-support-calling-ssrs-from-another-computer/)?

Comment: @McNets Yes it was preconfigured.After doing the SSL configuration i am able to access report from application.

Comment: Can you post the application code?

Comment: @McNets : It is a third party application and i don't have any access to their code.